# The menu links are not clickable on android + firefox

Tags: css

This is my website http://demo.themevan.com/citynews/ when you check it on android + firefox, click the menu button(top left of the top bar), the side menu will be opened, then click any menu link, you will found they are not clickable.

I guess this is a CSS issue, but I still can't find the reason, please help!

CSS:

```
.pushy{
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* enables momentum scrolling in iOS overflow elements */
}

.pushy a{
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    color: #b3b3b1;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    text-decoration: none;
    font:normal 1.5rem "Roboto Slab","Open Sans",Arial;
}

.pushy a:hover{
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
}
.pushy ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.pushy ul li{
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:0
}
.pushy ul.sub-menu{
    text-indent:15px;
}
.pushy ul.sub-menu ul{
    text-indent:30px;
}


/* Menu Movement */

.pushy-left{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-300px,0,0);
}
.pushy-open{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.container-push, .push-push{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
}

/* Menu Transitions */

.pushy, #body-container, .push{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
    -o-transition: -o-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
    transition: transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
}

/* Site Overlay */

.site-overlay{
    display: none;
}

.pushy-active .site-overlay{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9997;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-animation: fade 500ms; 
    -moz-animation: fade 500ms; 
    -o-animation: fade 500ms;
    animation: fade 500ms;
}
@keyframes fade{
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade{
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade{
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fade{
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Example Media Query */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .pushy{
        font-size: 1.0em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like some problem with your `$(".pushy").niceScroll({` inside citynew.js. Try to remove the entire `on('click')` you got there and update if it works.

Comment: Oh, yes, after I removed it,  the menu link was working fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem `$(".pushy").niceScroll({` inside citynew.js.
You should remove the entire `on('click')` to make it works.